# Keep getting "invalid email" message on any Civicrm/Joomla operation, such as register new individual or org address, or anything requiring email

Tags: joomla, email

Our email address is definitely valid, and everything else seems to set up fine in Civicrm in Joomla, but our org's email address always comes back as invalid.

The only clue we have is that when we became a Civicrm member, we used a different (personal) email address. Is that the problem? Or something else?

We get "Confirm from email error and configure event - civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Rule/Email.php on line 58"

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in 5.21. If you want to apply the patch now it's a small patch:
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-packages/pull/271/files

In fact for a quick temporary fix all you need to do is change that line 58 from

`$part = idn_to_ascii($part, 0, INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46);`

to

`$part = idn_to_ascii($part);`

More info: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1469

Comment: Demerit, thank you so much. We are so grateful, worked like a charm.